# Django Get None After User Authentication

Tags: python, django

```
def login_page(request):
    form = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {
        "form" : form
    }
    print("User logged in")
    print(request.user.is_authenticated())
    if form.is_valid():
        print(form.cleaned_data)
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user = authenticate(request, username = 'username', password = 'password')
        print(user)
        if user is not None:
            print(request.user.is_authenticated())
            login(request, user)
            # Recirect to a success page.
            # context['form'] = LoginForm()
            return redirect("/contact")
        else:
            # Return an 'invalid login' error message.
            print("Error")


    return render(request, "auth/login.html", context)
```

I try to create a login page but I get value of 'user' None so I took error everytime. I use Django 1.11.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to authenticate with constant credentials but need to authenticate with data from form.

```
username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
#                                        ^                   ^
#                        changed from 'username' and 'password' to variables
```

If your user provided wrong credentials, then [`authenticate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.authenticate) return `None`, since no user can be authenticated with those.

Comment: So if you haven't created user how you suppose to authenticate them?

Comment: Yeah you are right thanks just I am confused at a moment.